# Disable Contextual Action Bar and long click copy/paste

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar, long-click

i've searched a lot for this, but can't find any advice...
I'm providing my own implementation of the classic Action Bar so I declare in all the activities `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` but i want to get rid of the Contextual Action Bar too, the one with copy/paste/etc.. does anyone know how to achieve this?

Also i'll provide my own copy/paste feature, and only when needed, so i have to disable longclick feature too inside a webview. Every useful tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an instance of the ActionMode from the MultiChoiceModeListener class, and manually do mode.finish(). This is the hacky way to do it but the other way to do it maybe you can create a scenario where the onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) is called.

Comment: Could you elaborate a lil more? For now i've made everything unselectable, but i think i'll have to make some input text things selectable in the near future...

Comment: public void removeActionMode() {
  actionMode.finish();
 }
something like this! in the @override function like onCreate you can save an instance of the actionmode, and create a function to remove it!